# alter table add field taking forever

Tags: mysql

with a table of about 2 million rows,

```
alter table xxx add yyy smallint default 0
```

is taking forever, its current state is copying data to tmp table.  the table is using innodb, has a few indices.  tmp_table_size=4G and  max_heap_table_size = 4g, why would it take so long? how to speed it up?

Comment: How big is the table file-size wise?  As for improving the speed - get a faster disk, it's going to be disk-IO bound.  Saving it onto a different drive won't hurt either, though even with table_per_file set, it's not trivial to set that up. Without it, it's almost impossible.

Comment: ibdata1 is 219G.  I guess maybe that's why it's slow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the book "High Performance MySQL" Second Edition by Jeremy Zawodny & Peter Ziestev there is a high-speed, high-risk method of adding a column to table, regardless of table size. It goes something like this:

METHOD 1

Assuming db is the database where xxx resides

Step 1. CREATE TABLE zzz LIKE xxx;

Step 2. ALTER TABLE zzz add yyy smallint default NULL; -- Not using 0 for now

Step 3. Perform the following in the OS

service mysql stop
cd /var/lib/mysql/db
mv xxx.frm xxxold.frm
cp zzz.frm xxx.frm
service mysql start

Step 4. Try and see if xxx is accesible

If this does not work try this:

METHOD 2

Step 1. CREATE TABLE zzz LIKE xxx;

Step 2. ALTER TABLE zzz add yyy smallint default 0;

Step 3. INSERT INTO zzz (col1,col2,...colN) SELECT col1,col2,...colN FROM xxx;

Step 4. ALTER TABLE xxx RENAME jjj;

Step 5. ALTER TABLE zzz RENAME xxx;

The second method has to work. The first is recommended from that book I mentioned.

Give them a Try !!!

P.S. before trying the first method, backup everything (LVM snapshot)

Comment: is this myisam only since you mentioned .frm files

Comment: yes My first answer is MyISAM only. InnoDB is too convoluted to do since metadata aside from the .frm is sitting inside ibdata1. The second answer works regardless of storage engine.